# Should I initialize Firebase on my web for every js file

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Should i initialize my  `const firebaseConfig = {};` for every js file? on html

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the type of project you are working on.

Here is how it is done in React project

1. Create `Firebase` folder under `src` in React project
2. Create `config.js` in `Firebase` folder

Initialize the app in `config.js` and export it

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: //your API key,
  authDomain: "random-project.com"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export {app, db}
```

```
 // some other file 
 import { db } from '../Firebase/config';
 const citiesCol = collection(db, 'cities');
 const citySnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol);
```

You can read in more depth in official docs here:https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Answer (score 0):

Nope, just once. If possible on the root js file

Comment: how can i do that